# Can I customize popup share screen default of browser?

Tags: webrtc

I have a design for this popup, I've tried looking around, but not found any tutorial to edit the above popup with HTML/CSS.

Is it possible to customize it or is there an alternative?

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not - otherwise an attacker could present a misleading interface that gets a user to share something they do not want.